# Protractor clicking issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selenium, protractor

I am quite new to protactor and I am running a test case where in I have to click something. But, I have been having issues with it.

I want to click class = portal_element_image

```
describe 'Editor Changes', ->
    it 'Remove Image, Add terms and save', ->
        browser.actions().mouseMove($('.portal_element_image')).click(); //This is where it fails :-(
        #wait for the slide down to
        expect(driver.wait ( ->
            return driver.getCurrentUrl().then (url) ->
                return /demo/.test(url)
        ), timeout).toBeTruthy()
```

Basically nothing happens, it just times out. I want to click a particular class.

This is my structure.

```
<div> 
    <ol>
        <li>
            <div id="something" class="portal_element_image">
                <span> logo</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
element(by.id("something")).click();
```

(or)

```
element(by.css(".portal_element_image")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use element click(). You can find your element by id, css, ng-model, etc.

EG:

```
element(by.id("edit")).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 browser.actions().click($('.portal_element_image')).perform()
```

perform() did the thing.